# SoundCloud search API order by hottnes

Tags: soundcloud

The API method https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?oder=hotness&q= used to return great hot tracks with many plays on soundCloud. It now returns a bunch of random tracks with 0 plays. Has anyone else noticed it? Is there another way to get a bunch of hot tracks available on SoundCloud via the API?

Comment: they removed hotness parameter. check here http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param

Answer (score 3):

They removed hotness params.
Check here http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param